# Machine Learning : missions values for one entire class

Tags: python, machine-learning, missing-data, preprocessor

I am currently working on a Machine Learning project. It’s a binary classification (have to predict 1 or 0). I have skewed classes, my 0 classe has around 25k rows and the class 1 only 2k of rows (kind of anomaly detection)

My question is : for my class 1 (the anomaly class) I have a lot of values but for my class 0 the corresponding values are missing values. I mean I have values for the 1 but not for the 0 class.

Do I have to delete the features that have missing values for my class 0 ?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Think about what values you have available during inference time. Those are the values that can be part of your input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I shouldn’t use features that éléments are filled for my class 1 but missing values for my class 0, am I wrong?

Comment: In general yes. However, if your data during inference has the same characteristics (class 1 objects have more features than class 2 objects) you can just use the existence of these additional features to classify the objects.